# Android: What sets $(obj) variable in Makefile.modbuiltin?

Tags: android, linux, makefile, compilation

I'm working with a Mediatek MT8183 for a project and I'm trying to enable the SPI driver via "make menuconfig", but when I do the build breaks. Below is the output:

> $obj is [drivers/spi/mediatek] 
>   $obj is [drivers/spi/mediatek/mt8183]
>   /path/to/kernel/mediatek/4.4/scripts/Makefile.modbuiltin:26:
>   /path/to/kernel/mediatek/4.4/drivers/spi/mediatek/mt8183/Makefile:
>   No such file or directory

The "$obj is [blah]" print was a line I added to help debug. I can tell that Makefile.modbuiltin goes through the defconfig file and compiles all enabled modules. Now that SPI is enabled, the script loops through the SPI driver too.  The problem is, while drivers/spi/mediatek/Makefile exists, there is no drivers/spi/mediatek/mt8183 directory. Anyone know what is calling Makefile.modbuiltin? and giving it the $obj argument?